# How to build a Neural Network with only categorical variables?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, neural-networks

I've built mixed data NN, but I'm trying to build an NN that only has categorical variables.  In my problem, I cannot represent my categorical variables using the commonly used `NetEncoder[{"Class", VarLevels, "UnitVector"}]`, and each of my variables is a sequence of digits.  So input1 will be 001, or 020, and Input2 maybe 02435 or 05433

```
 net = NetGraph[{CatenateLayer[], 2, 
    SoftmaxLayer[]}, {{NetPort["Input1"], NetPort["Input2"]} -> 1, 
    1 -> 2}, 
    "Input1" -> 
    NetEncoder[{"Characters", Automatic, IgnoreCase -> True}], 
    "Input2" -> 
    NetEncoder[{"Characters", Automatic, IgnoreCase -> True}], 
    "Output" -> NetDecoder[{"Class", {"no", "yes"}}]]
```

I implemented this very simple net but I still get an error

```
 NetGraph::netinvgport: Output is neither a valid input or output port for the given NetGraph.
```

However, I don't know how to fix it.
Any help will be most appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

It works if you (1) connect the inputs to `UnitVectorLayer`'s and `SequenceLastLayer`s, (`CatenateLayer` can't take varying-length inputs) and (2) connect the linear layer to the softmax layer, like this:

```
net = NetInitialize@NetGraph[
   {
    UnitVectorLayer[], SequenceLastLayer[],
    UnitVectorLayer[], SequenceLastLayer[],
    CatenateLayer[],
    2,
    SoftmaxLayer[]},
   {
    NetPort["Input1"] -> 1 -> 2, NetPort["Input2"] -> 3 -> 4,
    {2, 4} -> 5 -> 6 -> 7
    },
   "Input1" -> 
    NetEncoder[{"Characters", Automatic, IgnoreCase -> True}], 
   "Input2" -> 
    NetEncoder[{"Characters", Automatic, IgnoreCase -> True}], 
   "Output" -> NetDecoder[{"Class", {"no", "yes"}}]]

net[<|"Input1" -> "123", "Input2" -> "456"|>]
```

> yes

Comment: Thank you very much for the prompt response!